# My beta fish is hanging out near the bottom of the tank.

Tags: fish

My beta fish is brand new. I just got him last week, and I use a Back To The Roots tank that filters out the nitrates in the fish waste by having a garden on the top that uses the nitrates for the plants to grow. Is he ok, or just lazy?

Comment: Is the tank heated?  How old is the fish?  Male/female?

Comment: [this here](http://pets.stackexchange.com/q/9504/5646) might get you started. Also did you use dechrorinated water to fill his tank or plain tap water? We are missing some informations to help you